# PHP Trying to get property of non-object with getElementsByTagName

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I have a simple scraper that fetches HTML using `DomDocument` and then displays the results.

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {
        $key = $li->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->textContent;
        $value = $li->getElementsByTagName('strong')->item(0)->textContent;
        $results[trim($key)] = trim($value);
        }
```

However, if the script fails to retrieve the HTML, or the options entered are wrong, it returns

```
Trying to get property of non-object

$key = $li->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->textContent;
```

How do I check if it exists?

I have tried to set that `$key` line as variable and check if length is greater than 0, but even as variable it fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

Check the return value of the `item` method:

```
$span = $li->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0);
if (!$span) {
  continue;
}
```

Actually you should *always* check the return values.

Comment: Thankyou, I have also added a checks on all the values.